# User based access to projects in OBIEE MUD

Tags: business-intelligence, obiee

We want to configure MUD to give access to specific projects for a set of users. In our current environment, all the projects can be accessed by everyone. We are looking to change it to user-based access. Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for can't be done in MUD. It can be done another way though - with a source-control based process, with security enforced through permissions on the source control tool (e.g. git with pull requests).

See : https://speakerdeck.com/rmoff/source-control-code-deployment-and-concurrent-development-for-obiee-12c